# How to make an ASPX button with round corners?

Tags: css, html

I tried to use CSS but my element is not accepting the `border-radius` property in the following code:

```
.button 
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

I am using C# and HTML5, is there any method to do this?

Hi everyone, to those who willing to help me, let me add some comment to it, what i expected is i want to access the c# behind code from the html itself, in this case, i do not mind if that is an aspx or not if your way can hit my objective, thanks in advance

Comment: Tips : All the SO souls get +10 in kindness if you provide some aspx/c# code ;-). And don't forget to add these tags to you question in order to provide a better question sorting and let people using these technologies know your issue.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/p/1597923/4057028.aspx#4057028?Re%3a+RoundedCornersExtender+don%26%23180%3bt+work

Comment: Hi Parveen, this doesnt help me because i want to make aspx button work so i can access the behind code from the aspx button. From what the link you gave me it want me to convert the button to div which not the result i want.

Comment: @RyanChong Can't you use a custom stylesheet?

Comment: Hi everyone, to those who willing to help me, let me add some comment to it, what i expected is i want to access the c# behind code from the html itself, in this case, i do not mind if that is an aspx or not if your way can hit my objective, thanks in advance